# Compare two last rows values

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a mysql table containing inventory data, each quarter I add a row with the last collected value.

Today:

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| Quarter      | Value             |
+--------------+-------------------+
|2012.Q4       |17000              |
|2013.Q1       |18000              |
|2013.Q2       |19000              |x
|2013.Q3       |26600              |x
+--------------+-------------------+
```

Next quarter, I will got

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| Quarter      | Value             |
+--------------+-------------------+
|2012.Q4       |17000              |
|2013.Q1       |18000              |
|2013.Q2       |19000              |
|2013.Q3       |26600              |x
|2014.Q1       |20000              |x
+--------------+-------------------+
```

I need to calculated the difference between two last rows, value and percentage each quarter

- Today, The result expected is +7600 (+40%) (rounded)
- Next quarter, the result expected is -6600 (-25%) (rounded)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN -1 * value ELSE value END) diff_value,
       ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN -1 * value ELSE value END) /
             SUM(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN 0 ELSE value END) * 100) diff_percent
  FROM
(
  SELECT quarter, value, @n := @n + 1 rnum
    FROM table1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) i
   ORDER BY quarter DESC
   LIMIT 2
) q
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4a88/13)** demo (**current quarter**)
Output:

```
| DIFF_VALUE | DIFF_PERCENT |
|------------|--------------|
|       7600 |           40 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/383b5/2)** demo (**next quarter**)
Output:

```
| DIFF_VALUE | DIFF_PERCENT |
|------------|--------------|
|      -6600 |          -25 |
```

Comment: +1 : At first I thought this would always have to scan the whole table, then I read closer and saw the `LIMIT 2`.  How could this be generalised to a case where there is also a `customer` column?  *(To get these values on a per-customer basis, and where each customer may not have data for the same quarters?)*

Comment: Top ! It's very clear now, many thank for your help !

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have luxuries like windowed functions, but you can use correlated sub-queries to find certain items.

```
SELECT
  previous_quarter.value                           AS previous_value,
  current_quarter.value                            AS current_value,
  current_quarter.value - previous_quarter.value   AS change_in_value
FROM
  yourTable   AS current_quarter
INNER JOIN
  yourTable   AS previous_quarter
    ON previous_quarter.quarter = (SELECT MAX(yourTable.quarter)
                                     FROM yourTable
                                    WHERE yourTable.quarter < current_quarter.quarter
                                  )
WHERE
  current_quarter.quarter = (SELECT MAX(yourTable.quarter)
                               FROM yourTable
                            )
```

Comment: Edit to change `<=` to `<` in the correlated sub-query.